# PostgreSQL 15 pg_read_file absolute path not allowed

Tags: postgresql

When not superuser but granted the pg_read_server_files role,

with statement

```
select * from pg_read_file('E:\PG_VERSION');
```

PostgreSQL 15 got a error "**absolute path not allowed**" while 14 is ok.

How non-superuser can read server file using absolute path? I don't want to put file into **PGDATA** directory.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I get the same behavior on both versions.  Double check that you have actually made the grants you think you did.  You need not only pg_read_server_files, but also execute on pg_read_file, on both versions.

Comment: @jjanes Data of pgsql15 are pgdump_all from 14.When I try to grant again,it says:"role "myuser" is already a member of role pg_read_server_files",and if pg_read_file function isn't granted,it will show "permission denied for function pg_read_file",not "absolute path not allowed".

Comment: What if you create a new database (in the existing pg15 system) and do the grant on pg_read_file there and test it there?

Comment: Also fail for absolute path.  In the source code genfile.c, there is a comment "Roles with privileges of the 'pg_read_server_files' role are allowed to access any files on the server as the PG user", don't know what make it misjudge at runtime.

Comment: okay，I find that PG15(in my side is 15.4) must enable **INHERIT** option to let "myuser" inherit rights from the parent roles, PG14(in my side is 14.8) needn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pg_read_server_files priv is (in v15) no longer inherited by a role which is declared as noinherit seems to be an intentional change, made in [6198420a](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=6198420ad8a72e37f4fe4964616b17e0fd33b808).  This was to make the behavior of predefined roles more consistent (under NOINHERIT) with that of regular roles.

So if you want to keep NOINHERIT, in v15 you will need to grant pg_read_server_files directly to myuser, just like you already (in v14) had to `grant execute on function pg_read_file` directly to myuser. Alternatively, you could just execute `set role = parent_role` where parent_role is the one which directly has the two grants before you do the thing needing those privs.

I notice this change in behavior was not mentioned in the release notes for 15.0, I don't know if that was an oversight or not.